# Unidentified 404 not found pages

Tags: internet-explorer, url, browser, http-status-code-404, browser-extension

We are getting lot of 404 page not found error which we can't find the reason with same pattern. We are not doing any redirect for this 404 pages or we are not giving link anywhere for this broken page links.

The common point for this errors is partly manipulated with same pattern; removing first segment of URL's. Example;

This is true URL's;

> site.com/category/news/title-of-the-content
>
> site.com/another-category/news/another-title-of-the-content
>
> ...

This is what we getting 404;

> site.com/category/news/
>
> site.com/another-category/news/
>
> ...

We are collection user agents for 404 errors, and here they are;

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
>
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0;
> .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
> 3.0.30729; InfoPath.2)
>
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

So this error only occurs in Internet Explorer.

We think this happens because of some IE plugins but can't find. Anyone have same problem? Or what we can do about this situation?

Thanks in advance.

**Bonus:**
[image]

Comment: Guilty. Sometimes I manually remove the article title from the url because I want to see ALL the news articles. Speaking seriously though, is there a referrer for the 404 entries?

Comment: @chue I don't think it's common behavior :) Getting thousands of error with this pattern. And there is no referrer.

Comment: @chuex I found some referrals which are from true URL. But most of them coming without referral.

Comment: At first glance, my thought was that it could be an automated crawler looking for common patterns in your URLs (possibly even to try and determine what CMS or site framework you're using). The only reasons I can think of why would be to crawl and scrape content for syndication on other sites, or to discover what site you're using and look for exploits (WordPress, Joomla, etc.)

Comment: Is `site.com/category/news` (without the last slash) a valid page? Is it reachable by clicking links on the home page? *Nice bonus, btw.*

Comment: @ADTC it's not valid page, it's 404. And there is no link for this page.

Comment: So you're saying thousands of IE browsers or users are requesting for a nonexistent page that you never provided a link for?

Comment: Yes. Most of them have not referral, some of them have from true URL like `site.com/category/news/title`.

Comment: But there is not any link or redirect for broken page  `site.com/category/news/`

Comment: Are you using .htacess to rewrite to a certain page eg. page.php?view=$1 or are those actual folders? If so you would need to have an index file in those folders.

Comment: try searching for `<script src="">` or `<img src="">`

Comment: @justsomeguy using nginx for rewrite, I can put a index file but want to find where these request come from and want to stop them instead of ignoring.

Comment: @Prozi I look up source codes again and again but there is no `src=""` too

Comment: maybe I'm not giving enough data for this problem but I think might be someone else have this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

It could have something to do with users using 'safe mode' from their browsers.
This link shows how the Mozilla Support addressed a similar situation https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1003468

Comment: He/she says problem solved after using 'safe mode' so as I guess this is most likely plugin issue, but which one? How we can find and prevent this?

Comment: You might want to look into coding something that allows your site to run seamlessly in safemode. That way whenever a user opens the website through safemode, there will not be any error messages

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. Problem not occur in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the thing: site.com/category/news/title-of-the-content. Category, news all refer to the folders within your server title of the content also refers to the folder but it might have a web page within the folder which is being shown on the browser. When you shorten the url, you are referring to the folder which might not have any page within it. This might be the cause of 404 pages being shown up as it is unable to find any page to be shown.