# Run jQuery code in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a stand alone html notepad which I need to run the following code.

```
jQuery(function($)
    {
        $
            .getJSON(
            'http://muslimsalat.com/daily.json?key=562736259fca2971c0f7b4cc838f1ecf',
            function(times)
            {
                $('.prayerTimesExample')
                    .append('Today in ' + times.title)
                    .append(' Fajr: ' + times.items[0].fajr)
                    .append(' Dhuhr: ' + times.items[0].dhuhr)
                    .append(' Asr: ' + times.items[0].asr)
                    .append(' Maghrib: ' + times.items[0].maghrib)
                    .append(' Isha: ' + times.items[0].isha)
                    .append(
                        ' by <a href="http://MuslimSalat.com">MuslimSalat.com</a>');
            });
    });'
```

So I made a the following html code but when i run it nothing happens

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="prayerTimesExample"></div>
<script>
    jQuery(function($)
    {
        $
            .getJSON(
            'http://muslimsalat.com/daily.json?key=562736259fca2971c0f7b4cc838f1ecf',
            function(times)
            {
                $('.prayerTimesExample')
                    .append('Today in ' + times.title)
                    .append(' Fajr: ' + times.items[0].fajr)
                    .append(' Dhuhr: ' + times.items[0].dhuhr)
                    .append(' Asr: ' + times.items[0].asr)
                    .append(' Maghrib: ' + times.items[0].maghrib)
                    .append(' Isha: ' + times.items[0].isha)
                    .append(
                        ' by <a href="http://MuslimSalat.com">MuslimSalat.com</a>');

            });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jfiddle i made http://jsfiddle.net/axL0u0q6/
Thank you 
Hope Im clear

Comment: Your code is using jQuery library. You should add `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>` or similar to your `<head>`. In jsfiddle, use the libraries dropdown on the left side to choose jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include jQuery;

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Add this code inside of head tags

Comment: If you not target IE 6, 7 or 8 you can use 2.1.1

Comment: Ah, there we go, I knew I was missing something. I'm fairly inimical to IE, particularly the older versions. :P

Comment: @Amadan you are not alone :D check my last question's bonus http://stackoverflow.com/q/26366736/910548

Comment: Awesome graph! :D I can totally believe in the existence of a causal relationship...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a library you need to include first.

```
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```